# SQL Query: Group by multiple columns in different tables

Tags: sql

I have two tables Users and Tasks. I need to get the count of tasks grouped by Users.Name and Tasks.Status. I need some help writing query to make my result look similar to the third table.

**Users**

```
|- Id -|- Name   -|
|- 1  -|- Robert -|
|- 2  -|- Bob    -|
|- 3  -|- Vicky  -|
|- 4  -|- Don    -|
|- 5  -|- Ron    -|
|- 6  -|- Harry  -|
```

**Tasks**

```
|- Id -|- Status     -|- user_id -|
|- 1  -|- Started    -|- 1       -|
|- 2  -|- Started    -|- 1       -|
|- 3  -|- Started    -|- 2       -|
|- 4  -|- Started    -|- 2       -|
|- 3  -|- Complete   -|- 1       -|
|- 4  -|- Complete   -|- 1       -|
|- 5  -|- Complete   -|- 2       -| 
|- 6  -|- Complete   -|- 2       -|
```

**Result**

```
|- Name   -|- Status   -|- Count -|
|- Robert -|- Complete -|- 2     -|
|- Robert -|- Started  -|- 2     -|
|- Bob    -|- Complete -|- 2     -|
|- Bob    -|- Started  -|- 2     -|
|- Vicky  -|- Complete -|- 0     -|
|- Vicky  -|- Started  -|- 0     -|
|- Don    -|- Complete -|- 0     -|
|- Don    -|- Started  -|- 0     -|
|- Ron    -|- Complete -|- 0     -|
|- Ron    -|- Started  -|- 0     -|
|- Harry  -|- Complete -|- 0     -|
|- Harry  -|- Started  -|- 0     -|
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to get zero's in the answer, you need to generate the rows first.  Here is a method for getting the results:

```
select u.name, s.status, count(t.userid) as cnt
from users u cross join
     (select distinct status from tasks) s left join
     tasks t
     on t.userid = u.id and t.status = s.status
group by u.name, s.status
order by u.name, s.status;
```

Note that this is standard SQL, so it will work in all the databases in your tags.

Answer (score 0):

Select name, status, count(name,status) 
from users inner join tasks on users.id = tasks.userid
group by name,status

Something along those lines, I am rusty

Answer (score 0):

You could do with having a table of status' as not all users have tasks in all status'. Without this, or selecting constants you land up having to use a sub query to get the list of the various status' which might be rather slow.

You can generate a list of them and cross join that with users, then left join those 2 against tasks.

Something like this:-

```
SELECT users.name, statii.status, COUNT(tasks.id)
FROM users
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT 'Started' AS status UNION SELECT 'Complete'
) statii
LEFT OUTER JOIN tasks
ON users.Id = tasks.user_id
AND statii.status = tasks.status
GROUP BY users.name, statii.status
```